# How to Run Srcutineer with mysql configuration?

Tags: mysql, elasticsearch, logstash

I want to implement data synchronization for my local db to elastic search. I found Scrutineer can do the job. But there is enough documentation for installation and running. How I can run it with mysql configuration?

Comment: Why don't you use logstash JDBC input plugin for that?

Comment: I have already indexed data with logstash JDBC input. Purpose here is to compare db data with indexed data and find out the difference.